# How set transparenty of element in autodesk-viewer?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to set the transparency of an element of a model, but I can't do it. I'm looking for a method that will do this, but the methods I tried did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewer does not really offer anything native/built-in to do this but THREE.js is always your friend in terms of graphical operations so long as you can reference the material of the target element (by its dbid/nodeid) in Viewer:

```
var fragList = viewer.model.getFragmentList();    

var fragIds = []

model.getData().instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(
  dbid, (fragId) => {
   fragIds.push(fragId)
});

    fragIds.forEach((fragId) => {
      //grab the material
      var material = fragList.getMaterial(fragId);

      if(material) {
        //set transparency
        material.opacity = 0.5;
        material.transparent = true;
        //mark for update
        material.needsUpdate = true
      }
    })
  });
  viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, true) //notify renderer to update
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don’t understand why enumNodeFragments undefined?

Comment: What version are you on? Just tried on v6.0-6.5 and worked fine. Did you wait till the model manifest is loaded (`GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` or later) to access its data?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not know how loaded GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT.

Comment: With put this code (  viewerApp.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, function () {
    instanceTree = viewerApp.model.getData().instanceTree;
    console.log(instanceTree);
  });) in this function (function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc)) and now I get instanceTree, but as before there isn’t enumNodeFragments.