# Why methods enumNodeFragments undefined?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I am working on a project in which we load two models. Loaded two models opened in the same viewer. At the moment I am looking for a way to establish transparency or hide elements.
For some reason, the hide and isolate methods work on one model, although I am passing the dbId elements of the two models.
I was advised to use the [enumNodeFragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275198/how-set-transparenty-of-element-in-autodesk-viewer/55275423?noredirect=1#comment97314269_55275423) method, but in my case it is always undefined, it simply does not exist. I've tried a lot of options, so that this method has appeared, but it was all in vain.
I would like to ask for advice on how I can find this method.
By the way, let me say that for me the most important thing is to find a way to hide the elements of the two models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like we discussed in the other thread this method is only available after the geometry data of the model is loaded - Viewer needs to tell whether the model is suitable for node fragment enumeration before it exposes the method:

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,()=> viewer.model.getData().instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, fragId => console.log(fragId)))
```

See live code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/85drt7qw/).

Comment: Thank you very much.
Sorry, but I still get undefined.
Here is [my code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oVVjeX) that I use.

Comment: I also tried to get in the console enumNodeFragments using the code you suggested, but I just do not get anything.

Comment: Did you pass in the correct dbid? My live code runs because `4` is a valid dbid for the model I am using...

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, your code is working.
I don’t know why, but I can’t convert my code so that it works. I added your code to my project and it worked. It turned out that you use viewer.start (), and I use a completely different code to load several models. I need to convert my code so that it works as it should.
I will be glad to advice, thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Bryan Huang. I continued to look for a solution for this problem and came to the following result. When I bring my svfUrl the value that you passed to options.document in your code, you get everything you need, but if I instead use the [following code](https://jsfiddle.net/am3p06w9/2/) as I get undefined.

The problem is in this code, but how can I change it?
doc.getViewablePath (initialViewable)

Comment: Hello Brian, I managed to get enumNodeFragments using this code. I want to get all the listed node fragments. I think I need to put 2 other values instead, but which one? By the way, I do not understand how further it can be used to hide the elements of the model?
I hope for your early reply, thank you very much.

              viewerApp.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, () => { 
               
                console.log(viewerApp.model.getData().instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(2, fragId => console.log(fragId)));
              });